# How to use Ecto's has_many and cast_assoc

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm new to Elixir and Ecto and I would need some help with Ecto's has_many and cast_assoc. Can't understand the basics, like how am I to create a new model with assoc one.

Here's my Has_Model:

```
defmodule Example.Has_Model do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Example.Repo
  alias Example.Has_Model

  schema "has_models" do
    has_many :belong_models, Example.Belong_Model
    field :name, string
    timestamps
  end

  def changeset(has_model, params \\ %{}) do
    has_model
    |> cast(params, [:name])
  end
end
```

and here's Belong_Model:

```
defmodule Example.Belong_Model do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Example.Repo
  alias Example.Belong_Model

  schema "belong_models" do
    belongs_to :has_model, Example.Has_Model
    field :name, string
    timestamps
  end

  def changeset(belong_model, params \\ %{}) do
    belong_model
    |> cast(params, [:name])
    |> cast_assoc(:has_model, required: true)
  end
end
```

**Now, what I try to do is first to create a Has_Model**

```
iex()> changeset = Example.Has_Model.changeset(%Has_Model, %{name: "I have"})
iex()> Example.Repo.insert(changeset)
```

This work ok.

**Then I'd like to create a new Belong_Model and use that previously created Has_Model with it:**

```
iex()> has = Example.Has_Model |> Example.Repo.get_by(name: "I have")
iex()> changeset = Example.Belong_Model.changeset(%Belong_Model, %{name: "I belong", belongs_to: has})
```

**And this is where it fails:**

```
** (Ecto.CastError) expected params to be a map, got: `%Example.Has_Model{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "has_models">, id: 1, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-10-04 19:39:38>, name: "I have", updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-10-04 19:39:38>, belong_models: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :belong_models is not loaded>}`
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:345: Ecto.Changeset.do_cast/4
    (example) lib/example/models/has_model.ex:15: Example.Has_Model.changeset/2
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset/relation.ex:99: Ecto.Changeset.Relation.do_cast/5
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset/relation.ex:235: Ecto.Changeset.Relation.single_change/5
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:571: Ecto.Changeset.cast_relation/4
    (example) lib/example/models/belong_model.ex:16: Example.Belong_Model.changeset/2
```

What's happening and what's the solution? I've tried to turn these parameters around the whole day but I just don't get it.

Comment: Try changing `%{name: "I belong", belongs_to: has}` -> `%{name: "I belong", has_model_id: has.id}`.

Comment: This adds the correct id, but now I can't use `cast_assoc(:has_model, required: true)` on Belong_Model changeset, as otherwise I get `errors: [has_model: {"can't be blank", []}]`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [build_assoc/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html#build_assoc/3)

```
iex()> has = Example.Has_Model |> Example.Repo.get_by(name: "I have")
iex()> belong_assoc = Ecto.build_assoc(has, :belong_models, has_model_id: has.id, name: "I belong")
iex()> Repo.insert!(belong_assoc)
```

And [cast_assoc/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3) should be use like this:

```
iex()> changeset = Example.Belong_Model.changeset(%Belong_Model, %{name: "I belong", has_model: %{name: "I have"})
iex()> Repo.insert!(changeset)
```

Note:

> The parameters for the given association will be retrieved from changeset.params and the changeset function in the association module will be invoked

Comment: With build_assoc example I can indeed include the associated model to the new one, but it doesn't use changeset to validate. If before Repo.insert!(belong_assoc) I do `changeset = Example.changeset(%Belong_Model{}, belong_assoc)` I again get that `(Ecto.CastError) expected params to be a map, got...` error.

Comment: So far the only working way to create a new Belong_Model using an existing Has_Model that I found is to use has_model_id without required: true on cast_assoc like this: `iex()> changeset = Example.Belong_Model.changeset(%Belong_Model, %{name: "I belong", has_model_id: has.id})`. If I use `cast_assoc(:has_model, required: true)` on Belong_Model changeset then I get an error saying it can't be empty, even though I have used has_model_id...